# How to recover HEAD problems in filtered repository?

Tags: git, git-branch

After having split the repository in my workspace into two by filtering, I cloned them "bare" into new origins, and then continued to work in a cloned workspace on the current branch without a problem.

Several commits later I merged my branch into `master`, then pushed it successfully.
Next I deleted the obsolete branches in my workspace.

However when I tried to get rid of obsolete branches in the "origin" repository too, I have problems like these:

- `git branch` lists branches that I cannot delete using `git branch -d` due to `fatal:  Couldn't look up commit object for HEAD`.
- `git fsck` complains: `notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (bitmap-generic)`

(I was hoping `git fsck` would identify those "dead" branches and clean them up, but obviously it did not)

Unfortunately I did not record the exact commands, but roughly this is what I did (based on the instructions given in section 19.1 of the Git book by Preißel and Stachmann, 1st edition (German)):

1. Make a backup: `git clone --no-hardlinks --bare orig.git backup.git`
2. Remove unwanted files: `git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch ...' --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty -- --all`
3. Reorganize: `git clone --no-hardlinks --bare backup.git new.git`
4. Drop backup: `rm -rf backup.git`
5. Check out `new.git` and work on it
6. Remove unneeded obsolete branches in `new.git`: `git branch -d ...`
   How can I fix these issues?
   Git version being used is 2.26.2.

Comment: "Next I deleted the obsolete branches in my workspace." Can you tell us how (command(s))?

Comment: What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: Aside from that, bare repositories don't have a branch checked out. If you want to delete a remote branch, you could use `git push --delete`.

Comment: @dan1st `git status` does not make sense in the repository, and `git push --delete` has the problem that the branches are already deleted in the workspace. Or will it work anyway?

Comment: It [should work because it is not dependent on the local repository.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---delete) Aside from this, you can use [`git push --prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---prune).

Comment: @dan1st `git push --delete` (with and without a branch name argument) always outputs "*fatal: --delete doesn't make sense without any refs*".

Comment: @dan1st `git push --prune` reports "*Everything up-to-date*", but I still have "*HEAD points to an unborn branch*" (I was able to get rid of the other branches using `git branch -D ...` before).

Comment: You need to provide what to delete when using --delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer is based on suggestions made by René Scharfe  (used with author's permission))

First try to assign a valid commit to the branch name.

```sh
% git branch --force bitmap-generic
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'bitmap-generic'.
% git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (173/173), done.
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (bitmap-generic)
...
```

Backup the repository (I used `cp -rp ...`) just in case you mess things up.

Assign some non-existing commit to the branch (the file didn't exist before; if it does, it's not needed):

```sh
% echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa >refs/heads/bitmap-generic
```

`git branch` indicated that `bitmap-generic` would be the current branch,
so that needed to be changed next:

```sh
# HEAD references the current branch
% cat HEAD
ref: refs/heads/bitmap-generic
```

Edit HEAD, replacing `bitmap-generic` with `master` (or any different branch).

```sh
% git branch --delete --force bitmap-generic
error: Couldn't look up commit object for 'refs/heads/bitmap-generic'
```

I did not expect that, but it does not seem to be important (I focused on the *branch name* while `git` focused on the *commit ID*); continue (make `git` happy):

```sh
# Re-assign branch "bitmap-generic" to HEAD commit:
% git branch --force bitmap-generic
```

Eventually:

```sh
% git branch --delete bitmap-generic
Deleted branch bitmap-generic (was 03aa7ca).
```

After that `git fsck` did no longer complain.